# How do I customize my scrolling navbar?

Tags: html, css, scroll, navbar

I currently have a navbar that stays relative as I scroll; what I want to do is have the bar span the entire top from left to right (responsive to different screens) with no gaps on either side. Also, when I move my cursor over the bar or click on one of the links it begins shrinking from the right to the left, down to about half of it's original size.

Here is a screenshot of my current navbar: http://prntscr.com/5x02ef

Here is my HTML:

```
  <div id="header">
        <div id="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#About Me">Me</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#Work">Work</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#Contact">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And here is my CSS code:

```
#header {
position: relative;
}

#navbar {
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 10px;
    margin-top:1.2%;
}

ul {
    position: fixed;
    margin: 0px;
    height: auto;
}

li {
    display: inline;
    border: 2px solid rgb(73, 73, 73);
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
    border-top:none;
    padding-top: 1.562em;
    padding-bottom: 1.562em;
    padding-left:14%;
    padding-right:14%;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;       
}
```

Comment: Whats the output now and whats the expected output? Can you add screen shots, please?

Answer (score 0):

is this what you want?

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/PrakharThakur/ksfqv5bf/embedded/result/

```css
#navbar {
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}
body{
    text-align:center;
}
#header {
    position: relative;
    text-align:center;
}
ul {
    
    height: auto;
}
li {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 2px solid rgb(73, 73, 73);
    padding-top: 1.562em;
    padding-bottom: 1.562em;
    padding-left: 6.25em;
    padding-right: 6.25em;
    border-radius: 5px 5px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
    <div id="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#About Me">Me</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#Work">Work</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#Contact">Contact</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/PrakharThakur/ksfqv5bf/embedded/result/

Comment: This is closer, thanks; However now the elements are not fixed at the to of the page, I want them to scroll and stay at the top as I navigate my page. Also, I'd like for it to be one continuous bar instead of three individual bars, and have it span the page.

Comment: i have edited the fiddle, check out http://jsfiddle.net/PrakharThakur/ksfqv5bf/1/

Comment: I just updated the question and the code in it along with a screenshot where I am right now; thanks, I really appreciate it.